# Как разбить  значение строки в массиве на новые значения второго массива?

Tags: веб-программирование, массивы, php

Имеется файл данными значениями:

```
version = ‘1.3.15’
source.id = ‘1’
source.path = ‘some/path’
login.remember = ‘1’
login.name = ‘userName’
login.password = ‘password’
awful.layout = ‘split’
awful.layout.suit = ‘tile’
```

необходимо перебрать все значения и записать их в новый массив вот такого вида:

```
$config = array(
    ‘version’ => ‘1.3.15’,   
    ‘source’  => array(
    ‘id’ => ‘1’,
    ‘path’ => ‘some/path’,
),’
)
```

не знаю как правильно разбить=(

```
$lines = file_get_contents('file.txt',  FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
echo("<b>вот содержимое \$lines= $lines</b>");
echo"<br>";
$res = explode('=', $lines);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: @Анатолийй, пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @sergiks
>$lines = file_get_contents('file.txt',  >FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
>echo("<b>вот содержимое \$lines= $lines</b>");
>echo"<br>";
>$res = explode('=', $lines);
>print_r($res);

не знаю как правильно и чем разбивать=\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте по строками, или сделайте сначала разбивку по "\n", потом по "=", потом левую часть разбивайте по ".", как то так:

```
//разбиваем файловую строку по строкам
$resLines = expolde("\n",$lines);
//наш результирующий массив
$resArray = array();
//по всем строкам
foreach($resLine as $resLineValue)
{
    //разбиваем на правую и левую часть выражение
    $resLine = explode("=", $resLineValue);
    $name = $resLine[0];
    $value = $resLine[1];

    //Выделяем массив значений имён.
    $names = explode(".",$name);
    //устанавливаем указатель на начало нашего массива
    $resWriter = &$resArray;
    //находим элемент хеша в который надо положить значение
    if(is_array($names))
    {
        foreach($names as $separate)
        {
            //если нету нужного имени в хеше, создаём его.
            if(!isset($resWriter[$separate]))
                $resWriter[$separate] = array();

            $resWriter = &$resWriter[$separate];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $resWriter = &$resWriter[$names];
    }
    //Устанавливаем значение.
    $resWriter = $value;
}
```

Comment: @Чад чего то не соображу как наладить...и как понимать вот эту строку 
>$resWriter = &$resArray;
с символом &

Comment: Символ & означает ссылку. Что Вы хотите наладить?

Comment: @Чад вывод, а то бес коментов не понимаю и что выводить

Comment: @Анатолийй, наслаждайтесь :-)